# How to run a Java program on every file in a directory in UNIX?

Tags: java, shell, unix

I have a java class file which I need to run on every file in a directory. Its in the form of

java StripEnronHeaders < FILE NAME >

I'm very new to UNIX so I'm wondering if there is a UNIX command or set of commands that will allow me to run that java program recursively for every file in a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec java StripEnronHeaders {} \;
```

though this will execute java for EVERY file you find. If that app can accept multiple files on the command line, then this'll be more efficient:

```
find . -type f|xargs java StripEnronHeaders
```